# kali linux airmon-ng fixed channel issue

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

I bought a tp-link ac1300 dual band 2.4 & 5 GHz wifi adapter for kali linux'

All monitor mode packet injection etc work fine but if I try to display `airodump-ng -cxx -bssid xxxxxx wlan1` for only the target AP it shows two channels at the left side and a fixed channel at the right side and after that I can't seem to work aireplay-ng command for de authentication..it gives error eg no such bssid available or sometimes like wlan1 is on channel xx but AP uses channel xxx....etc.

I haven't found any solution for this I tried everything like changing fixing channel stop process etc..but no luck ...may be this wifi adapter is not supported because this problem do not occur with internal build wifi ...

**note-** I have internal built athers chip set WiFi which works all fine but never captures hanshakes even when reconnect too close ap..

Can someone solve this fixed channel and handcapture issue please ?

Comment: See this list of wireless adapters for Kali that support monitor mode.    https://www.javatpoint.com/best-wifi-adapters-for-kali-linux   ...  I do not think your own TP Link works for what you want.

Comment: i have tested all monitor mode and packet injection working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this list of Wireless USB Adapters that work with Kali and support Monitor Mode.

[Kali wireless for monitor mode](https://www.javatpoint.com/best-wifi-adapters-for-kali-linux)

The card you have does not work for Kali / Monitor Mode airodump, so you will need to pick a card that supports Monitor Mode and use the USB card for your machine.

The cards in the list should also support  airodump-ng

I use a Panda PAU08 USB card

Comment: yeah may be that is the issue ..it support monitor mode but may be not airodump-ng but it works all fine with my internal wifi adapter ..